# Virtuals and populate not showing on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am I doing something wrong here? I've been trying to display virtuals on Party I tried simple virtual like the "slogans" just to check. I am also having problem with populate. I kinda hate this cuz its not throwing me any errors  nor warning either and i dont know whats happening behind it. Kinda frustrating

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set("debug", true);

const partySchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Please provide a party'],
       unique: [true, 'Party already exists. Please try another party name'],
       maxLength: [20, 'Party Name should be less than 20 characters'],
       minLength: [4, 'Party Name should be greater than 4 characters']
   },
   slogan:{
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Please provide a slogan'],
       maxLength: [20, 'Party Name should be less than 20 characters'],
       minLength: [5, 'Party Name should be greater than 5 characters']
   },
   createdAt:{
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now()
   }
},{
   toObject: {
       virtuals: true
     }
     ,toJSON: {
       virtuals: true
     }
});

partySchema.virtual('slogans').get(function () {
   // use an ordinary function so you can get the "this"
   return this.slogan
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign id was not an ObjectId data type